# Auto-Assign Next Assignment In Google Classroom API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

In google classroom, you can schedule assignments by date. Is it possible to use the API to automatically assign the next scheduled assignment once a student has marked the current assignment as complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API doesn't seem to provide an easy way to do that.

If you look at the documentation for the Classroom API there is no out-of-box mechanism to track when a student assignment is "turned in". You'd likely have to code something yourself to [poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) the state of a submitted assignment for a given student and if the submission is flagged as "turned in" use the API to trigger the next assignment in the sequence. A viable approach but not exactly trivial to implement.

Ironically [the API supports push notifications for roster changes](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications). Maybe google will expand this someday to include tracking submission state. You should consider posting a feature request using [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191645%20status:open) - this will at least put this need on google's radar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. After a cursory look at the API, I concluded what you just said. I was hoping that maybe there was a way.